# Skyrim crashes on start. Do I need a new sound card?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, technical-issues

In my computer I have both a Sound Blaster Live! 5.1 SB0220 card and a Realtek ALC850 chipset on an [MSI K9N4 nForce 500](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130071) motherboard. My game crashes on launch, just after the Bethesda logo fades. I've tried both cards with multiple drivers, with the same results.

I've seen the workaround which involves changing the audio sample rate to 16bit 44100Hz, but to the best of my knowledge, both cards seem to only support a 16bit 48000Hz sample rate. Are there any other workarounds, or does Skyrim simply not support my hardware?

Comment: Skyrim does support the motherboard with Realtek audio chipset. I would guess it's the Soundblaster card with old drivers.

Comment: I've got Skyrim running with 48kHz. Have you given it a try?

Comment: I removed the Sound Blaster card and all drivers except for Realtek AC'97 version 6305 and I still have the same crash.

Comment: @Dempf Did the most recent Skyrim patch fix this issue for you?

Comment: You may also want to check that your video card settings are set to actually use the proper video card. For example, mine was set by default to use the integrated instead of my gpu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when installing Skyrim and my problem was the ATItray tool and the option "Swap pixel median" from the extended option in the 3D menu.

I recommend to uninstall the ATI tray tools or to disable this option.